# Problem with a wide table which spans multiple pages

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, width

I'm doing my PhD thesis, I'm new on LaTeX and I'm struggling with my tables. 
As seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL6sH.jpg my table spans two pages, but in the second page it doesnt align properly.

I already used tabularx, longtable and \setlength\LTleft{-1cm} but nothing seems to help, also read other Q&A about it, and the problem persists. 
I need my tables to span multiple pages, the table must be centered and the caption start at the left. 
The table is wide, but I need it to shrink it into a portrait layout.

I have the next code which gives me a table spanning two pages, but in the second one, the table doesn't align properly, it moved about certain pixels towards the right:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PREAMBLE: Contains packages and user-defined commands and settings
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{dcolumn,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox} %para ajustar las tablas
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% APPENDICES

\begin{appendices} % Using appendices environment for more functunality
\include{Appendix2/appendix2}
\end{appendices}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%appendix2.tex file
\subsection{CSH table for peptide xxxx in xxxx mM DPC}
\label{table:CSH-xxxxx-DPC} 
\setlength\LTleft{-1cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lllll lllll lll}
\caption{chemical shifts (ppm from DSS)  for peptide ----}\\  

\endfirsthead
 \endhead

\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Residue}}   &
\textbf{HN}  & 
\textbf{ H\textalpha }& 
\textbf{H\textbeta}  &   
\textbf{H\textgamma }   &
\textbf{H\textdelta }   &
\textbf{H\textepsilon }     &   
\textbf{H\textzeta }   &
\textbf{C\textalpha  } 
\\[6pt]
\midrule


Arg &   845 &   7.37    &   7.37    &   7.37    ,   7.37    &   7.37    ,   7.37            &   7.37    ,   7.37    &   7.37        7.37    &   6.70    ,   6.57    &   56.76   \\


\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\clearpage
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why do you use `tabularx` since you have no `X` column? Also, did you compile twice?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome: 
I used tabularx because it was what it was working for me to span the table into multiple pages, I tried tabular alone and got several errors.  
I compiled twice and the problem persists.

Thanks for the help

Comment: you not use `longtable` but `tabularx`. if you like to have it over two (or more) pages, you need to load `ltablex` package. to help you, we need to see complete small document with related packages in preamble no just code snippet.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. When I used longtable I got several errors too. I will attach now more code.

Comment: @Zarko I already tried with longtable, but the problem persists.

Comment: i don't know, how you tried. anyway, please reduce your document example to minimum, we haven't your files ...

Comment: Ok, I'll reduce it now

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**

after your response i second review my answer again ... and find some glitches in code, which arise from not understanding of table context. now i suspect, that table actually has nine columns. in answer for document class i use `book` instead `PhDThesisPSnPDF` which i haven't.

you can use `tabularx`, but in this case at least one column had to be of `X` type:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{report}%{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex}
\newcommand\mcbf[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{#1}}}    % <-- added

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}    % <-- added

\begin{document}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}  % <-- added
\keepXColumns                      % <-- added
\small                             % <-- added
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}          % <-- added 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{10}{X}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X*{8}{l} @{}}
\caption{\ce{^1H} and \ce{^13 C\alpha} chemical shifts (ppm from DSS)  for peptide --- in \ce{H2O}/\ce{D2O} (9:1 v/v), \SI{30}{mM} DPC, pH 3.5, \SI{35}\degreeCelsius}\\
    \toprule
 \textbf{Residue}       &
\mcbf{HN}               &
\mcbf{\ce{H\alpha}}     &
\mcbf{\ce{H\beta}}      &
\mcbf{\ce{H\gamma}}     &
\mcbf{\ce{H\delta}}     &
\mcbf{\ce{H\epsilon}}   &
\mcbf{\ce{H\zeta}}      &
\mcbf{\ce{C\alpha}}   \\
     \midrule
\endfirsthead
% table headers on the next page
\caption{\ce{^1H} and \ce{^13 C\alpha} chemical shifts \dots (cont.) }  \\
    \toprule
 \textbf{Residue}       &
\mcbf{HN}               &
\mcbf{\ce{H\alpha}}     &
\mcbf{\ce{H\beta}}      &
\mcbf{\ce{H\gamma}}     &
\mcbf{\ce{H\delta}}     &
\mcbf{\ce{H\epsilon}}   &
\mcbf{\ce{H\zeta}}      &
\mcbf{\ce{C\alpha}}   \\
     \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{9}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape continue on the next page} % <-- added
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
Arg 845 &   7.37    &   7.37    &   7.37, 7.37    &   7.37, 7.37    &   7.37, 7.37
    &   7.37 7.37   &   6.70, 6.57  &   56.76   \\
Arg 845 &   7.37    &   7.37    &   7.37, 7.37    &   7.37, 7.37    &   7.37, 7.37
    &   7.37 7.37   &   6.70, 6.57  &   56.76   \\
% ... 
    \bottomrule    
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

this code need to be compiled three times that it obtain correct form.

- changes in code are indicated by `% <-- added`.
- i suggest to use

  - `mhchem` packages for chemistry formulas,
  - `siunity` package for units.
- because the table is slightly wider than text width two measures are considered (if this is not the case with original document case, you can remove this change):

  - `\small` font size is used
  - reduced is distance between columns from default value of `6pt` to `5pt`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that works perfectly. Also thank you for the suggestions in using the SI units and the "continue on the next page".

Comment: @DNA, see edited answer. if answer solve your problem, you can accept it by clicking on up-pen at top left side of answer :-). by the way, structure of your table is not clear to me. i suspect that the first two columns should be merged and contents of merged cells is `Arg 845`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bernard and @Zarko, I finally found the problem:

I changed now to longtable and added the following lines:

```
\setlength\LTleft{-1cm}
\setlength\LTright{-1cm}
\begin{longtable}{lllll lllll lll}

%%%%%%content

\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\clearpage
```